# How to rewrite rules for two subfolders using mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

I would need to do something like this:

```
########## SITE 1 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /mysite1  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA] 

########## SITE 2
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /mySecondSite   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem is that i can only use one `.htaccess` file as I am using [Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite 3](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) over windows 2003 Server.

Is there a way to combine both .htaccess files in just one of them and making them work properly?

I have tried this just to test if `mysite` would work without the `RewriteBase`, but seems not to work:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^mysite1/(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^mysite1/(.*)$ mysite1/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^mysite2/(.*)$ mysite2/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost works but if i use it as you did, the CSSs of the second site (mysite2) doesn't load. If i invert the order of the rules, then it happends only with mysite1. Therefor, i guess it still being something wrong in the rules as depending on the order it acts in one way or another. What could it be??

Comment: Ok. It seems that the first two `RewriteCond` about files or folders are not being applied to the second `RewriteRule`. I've solved it adding again the 2 `RewriteCond` after the first `RewriteRule`. It works well now but... is it correct? Why is it happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your directory names correspond with the domain names e.g.   www.**mySite**.com has it's files located in directory **/mySite/** and   www.**myOtherSite**.com  has it's files in /**myOtherSite**/  then you could try the following:

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}        ^(www\.)?([^.]*)\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .*    /%2/index.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: One of the sites has a domain (`www.website.com`), the other is just a subfolder inside a subdomain (`www.demo.website.com/website2/`) I dont know if it would be so simple in this case.